# Code coverage for arrow function in Express context

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, istanbul

How to achieve code coverage for the line containing context?

```
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express"
const server = new ApolloServer({
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
})
```

I can write a test that fails if this line is not present, however, it itself does not convince code coverage from Jest to complain. Specifically, it says about that line:

- statement not covered
- function not covered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

`server.ts`:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    _: Boolean
  }
`;

function contextFunction({ req, res }) {
  return { req, res };
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  context: contextFunction,
});

export { server, contextFunction };
```

`server.spec.ts`:

```js
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { server, contextFunction } from './server';

describe('server', () => {
  it('should initialize apollo server', () => {
    expect(server).toBeInstanceOf(ApolloServer);
  });
  it('should create context', () => {
    const mockedReq = {};
    const mockedRes = {};
    const actualValue = contextFunction({ req: mockedReq, res: mockedRes });
    expect(actualValue).toEqual({ req: mockedReq, res: mockedRes });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/58226940/server.spec.ts
  server
    ✓ should initialize apollo server (4ms)
    ✓ should create context (1ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 server.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.484s, estimated 6s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/tree/master/stackoverflow/58226940

Comment: Thank you @slideshowp2, I have learned a lot from your example, it is working now. I had no idea how to extract anonymous function to the named function - turns out, you just write the function name `context: contextFunction`, not as `context: contextFuction({req, res})` as I would have expected.